# Extract respiratory rate (BPM) from ECG signal using python

Tags: python, signal-processing

I am trying to extract respiratory rate (RR) in Breaths Per Minute (BPM), from an ECG signal using neurokit2 library.

I found this [ECG-Derived Respiration (EDR) Analysis](https://rpanderson-neurokit2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/edr.html) at the neurokit2 documentation that seems to be helpful, but I am not sure if I understand it well.

I can not find online, a code that someone actualy does this.

Can someone help me?

So far, I have coded the below, but I am not sure if this is correct:

```
ecg = nk.data('ecg_1000hz.csv')

sampling_rate = 1000

 
# Visualize signal

nk.signal_plot(ecg)

# Check the results of every possible method at function ecg_rsp()  
method_name_lst = ["vangent2019", "sarkar2015", "charlton2016", "soni2019"]

 
# Clean an ECG signal to remove noise and improve peak-detection accuracy.

# Different cleaning method are implemented.

# Return: Vector containing the cleaned ECG signal.

cleaned_ecg = nk.ecg_clean(ecg_signal = ecg, sampling_rate = sampling_rate, method = "neurokit")

 
# Find R-peaks in an ECG signal using the specified method.

# The method accepts unfiltered ECG signals as input,

# although it is expected that a filtered (cleaned) ECG will result in better results

rpeaks, info = nk.ecg_peaks(cleaned_ecg, sampling_rate = sampling_rate)


# Calculate signal rate (per minute) from a series of peaks. It is a general function that works

# for any series of peaks (i.e., not specific to a particular type of signal). It is computed as

# ``60 / period``, where the period is the time between the peaks (see func:`.signal_period`).

# Return: A vector containing the rate (peaks per minute).

ecg_rate = nk.signal_rate(rpeaks, sampling_rate = sampling_rate, desired_length = len(rpeaks))

 
for method_name in method_name_lst:

    print("Method: {}\n".format(method_name))

  
    # Extract ECG-Derived Respiration (EDR), a proxy of a respiratory signal based on heart rate.

    # Return: A Numpy array containing the derived respiratory rate.

    # ????? Is this actually the respiratory signal ????

    resp_signal = nk.ecg_rsp(ecg_rate, sampling_rate = sampling_rate, method = method_name)

   
    #nk.signal_plot(resp_signal)

   
    # Clean a respiration signal

    # Return: Vector containing the cleaned respiratory signal.

    rsp_cleaned = nk.rsp_clean(resp_signal, sampling_rate = sampling_rate)

   
    # Find respiration rate

    # Return: Instantenous respiration rate.

    rsp_rate_onsets = nk.rsp_rate(rsp_cleaned, sampling_rate = sampling_rate, method = "trough")

    rsp_rate_xcorr = nk.rsp_rate(rsp_cleaned, sampling_rate = sampling_rate, method = "xcorr")

   
    # ??? Is this correct ????

    print("\tMean RR (Trough): {}\n".format(np.mean(rsp_rate_onsets)))

    print("\tMean RR (Xcorr): {}\n".format(np.mean(rsp_rate_xcorr)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited the previous answer by integrating the information you add in the comments.

From what you wrote in the comments, you have a twofold problem:

- extract respiratory rate
- resample it in order to have a signal of specific size

The signal extraction part is correct, while for the second part you can use the scipy library to do the resampling, below I have written a piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# original signal and its length (l1)
l1 = 100 
original_signal = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 1.0 * np.linspace(0, 1, l1))

l2 = 50  # Length of the resampled signal

# Use the signal.resample function to downsample the signal
resampled_signal = signal.resample(original_signal, l2)

# Print the lengths of the original and resampled signals
print("Original Signal Length:", len(original_signal))
print("Resampled Signal Length:", len(resampled_signal))

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(original_signal, label='Original Signal')
plt.title('Original Signal')
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(resampled_signal, label='Resampled Signal')
plt.title('Resampled Signal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This is the result: the original and the resampled signal, they look the same, but if you look at the x-axis you can see that the second one is shorter

[image]

Comment: Hello Marco. Thanks for your quick response. So the part that I compute the final Respiratory Rate using the mean of the array that returned from the function rsp_rate() is also correct? This is actually my final RR?

Comment: yes, that is correct. The only clarification to be made is that you get a value for each minute of signal. So if the frequency is 100hz, it means that 100 samples of your signal refer to one second and 6000 samples refer to one minute. So in your rsp_rate you will get a value for every 6000 samples of your original signal. Averaging is correct, if there are small variations between rsp_rate values, but if on the other hand for example a signal refers to a time when a person at first walks, then runs, you probably lose this information by averaging... but I don't think this is the case.

Comment: Thank you very much Marco. I have another question. The function rsp_rate() returns me an array with the respiratory rate. In my occasion, my respiratory signal has shape 6001and also the array from the above function has shape 6001. I want the array that the function rsp_rate() returns, to be shape 481. Do you have any idea? Here is the documentation of the function: https://github.com/neuropsychology/NeuroKit/blob/master/neurokit2/rsp/rsp_rate.py

Comment: Can I ask you the freq parameter value in this case? And why 481? I didn't understand if you expect this value or if you want it.... I'm just asking for a better understanding

Comment: Well I have a dataset that contains an ECG and a respiratory signal sampled at 125Hz and a respiratory rate vector sampled at 1Hz  (with shape (481,)). This is the dataset https://physionet.org/content/bidmc/1.0.0/. I want to take the ecg signal, find the respiratory signal and from that I want to extract the respiratory rate,  as you understand from the code above. So, I want the respiratory rate vector that I extract, to be the exact same length as the initial respiratory rate (481 length),  in order to compare them.

Comment: So you propose to apply the code you wrote, in my respiratory rate vector, in order to resample it the desired length?

Comment: Exactly! In this way you don't loose the information of the computed signal, but make it suitable for the following computations